# Select all from Table A, one column from Table B - LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, left-join

Psuedocode:

```
SELECT (* from tableA, columnX from TableB) 
FROM TableA 
LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA.columnY = TableB.columnX;
```

At the moment, I seem to be having to specify every column from TableA and the one column from TableB in the select call to get the result I want, which can become a pain when TableA has 30 columns. Surely there is an easier way?

Comment: Do you mean, `SELECT TableA.*, TableB.columnX`?

Comment: I did not know TableA.* was valid syntax. Thank-you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax you appear to be looking for would be,

```
SELECT TableA.*, TableB.columnX
FROM TableA 
LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA.columnY = TableB.columnX
```

The `TableA.*` syntax will return all columns associated to `TableA`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, TableB.columnX
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB
ON TableA.columnY = TableB.columnX;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
SELECT tableA.* , TableB.columnX FROM TableA  LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA.columnY = TableB.columnX;
```

This will grab all columns from tableA and single column from TableB.